# What is "hoolihan" in "Old Paint" song?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, lyrics

Lyric is:

> I ride an old paint, I lead an old dan
>        I'm goin' to Montana to throw the hoolihan
>        They feed in the coulees, they water in the draw
>        Their tails are all matted, their backs are all raw

But what is a hoolihan, please?

Comment: I have suspected for years that it is an old tan, rather than an old dan. Paint and tan being color descriptors of horses.

Comment: A crop of dental floss?

Comment: I believe this guy (Ray toward the bottom of the website)...that it's [old dan.](http://www.cowboypoetry.com/whoknows2.htm) I don't think *tan* is used by horse people as a horse color....there's dun, light chestnut, blond, palomino, cream, cremello...but not usually tan.

Comment: I lead an old Dan Dan is a favorite name for horses..

Answer (score 11):

From http://www.cowboypoetry.com/whoknows2.htm

> Hoolihan
>
> We get questions about the meaning of 
>   "hoolihan."
>
> In the 1933 Cowboy Lore, by Jules Verne Allen (more about that here) one
>   interesting section of commonly used
>   terms includes entries such as
>   "HOOLIHANING, the act of leaping
>   forward and alighting on the horns of
>   a steer in bull-dogging in a manner to
>   knock the steer down without having to
>   resort to twisting the animal down
>   with a wrestling hold. Hoolihaning is
>   barred at practically all recognized
>   contests."
>
> In response to our posting that information, Rod Miller wrote "The
>   line 'throw the Hoolihan' that appears
>   in 'I Ride an Old Paint' almost surely
>   refers to a type of loop used in
>   roping, often for catching horses. A
>   hoolihan is a kind of backhand loop,
>   but distinct from a regular backhand
>   loop in that the roper rolls his wrist
>   and the loop rolls over in the air.
>   That rolling motion also describes the
>   motion of a hoolihanned steer in
>   bulldogging -- it does a forward roll.
>   It is unlikely that the line in the
>   song has reference to bulldogging as
>   Bill Pickett is credited with
>   inventing that particular activity
>   long after, I suspect, 'I Ride an Old
>   Paint" was first written and sung."
>
> Rod also referred us to the definition of "hooley-ann" in Ramon F.
>   Adams' Cowboy Lingo (1936): "The term
>   'hooley-ann' was a roping term and the
>   throw was used mostly to catch calves
>   out of a bunch and to rope horses. The
>   roper rode with his loop in his hand,
>   and when the chance presented itself,
>   he swung the loop backward instead of
>   forward, and as it came over it was
>   turned in such a way as to cause it to
>   flatten out before it reached the head
>   of the animal to be roped.  Just one
>   swing and it could be tossed thirty
>   feet forward. The size of the loop
>   depended upon the distance it was to
>   be thrown and the size of the animal.
>   A good calf-roper who used the
>   'hooley-ann' might be thirty feet from
>   a wee tot of a calf and start a loop
>   that a beef steer could pass through,
>   but the noose ran out by reason of the
>   distance, and by the time it reached
>   the calf, it was barely large enough
>   to pass around the calf's neck."
>
> Adams' definition of "hoolihaning" is word-for-word the same as that in
>   Jules Verne Allen's Cowboy Lore cited
>   above.  Cowboy Lore was published
>   three years before Adams' book.
>
> A history site here:
>   http://historywired.si.edu/detail.cfm?ID=49
>   claims "A Hoolihan is a
>   left-hand-and-around horse throw. The
>   rope is released with minimum of
>   movement."
>
> A site here: 
>   http://home.att.net/~basicbrian/iride.html
>   has the song and a note: "A very
>   dangerous rodeo move, jumping from a
>   horse at full gallop onto a moving
>   cow, to flip it over. The move, named
>   after it's originator, is now banned
>   in competition."
>
> The PBS History of the West site
>   places the song in the 1868-1874
>   period, but without documentation.
>
> In May, 2006, Don comments:
>
> "My Dad, who grew up in the 1920's and 1930's on a ranch in west Texas,
>   said that throwing the hoolihan could
>   be used to mean 'getting ready to die'
>   similar to 'headin' for the last
>   roundup.'"
>
> In July, 2006, Milton writes:
>
> Hoolihan is a loop thrown, usually when you're roping horses.

Comment: Neat information...

Comment: +1: Jay, a cowboy poet somewhere is smiling right now ...

Comment: Ian Tyson spells it a little differently in The Gift: "the twisting wrist of the Houlihan throw" but it's clearly the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

In rodeo, the *hula hand* is a common way to throw a lasso. The term was corrupted into "houlihan."

Comment: Citation needed, ideally a reputable online source.